# Remove indentation by fbox

Tags: indentation, boxes

**Here is an update of my question, showing what I really mean:**

I want to add a frame to my **inner** minipage.

But `\fbox` indents the minipage so that it causes an `overfull hbox` error

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} %works fine
\begin{center}
a

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\hfill
b

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

\begin{itemize}
\item one
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
c

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

\begin{itemize}
\item two
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

d
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame} %overfull hbox
\begin{center}
a

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\hfill
b

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

\begin{itemize}
\item one
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
c

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

\begin{itemize}
\item two
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}
\end{minipage}

d
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are several solutions, with and without the `framed` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth} % fbox only for showing problem
% insert some tikz picture
\noindent
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
some text
\end{minipage}}
\end{minipage}}
\hfill
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth} % fbox only for showing problem
% insert some tikz picture
\begin{framed}\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
some other text
\end{minipage}\end{framed}
\end{minipage}}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth} % fbox only for showing problem
% insert some tikz picture
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{framed}
some other text
\end{framed}\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I actually realize, that your first solution is what I was searching for. Thanks. I don't know if you want to update your answer, so it fits my actual problem.